# How do people normally model classes which implement an interface in declarations?

Tags: flowtype

For example, I have something like this:

```
declare module 'rxjs' {
  declare interface CoreOperators<T> {
    static merge<R>(...sources: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>;

    map<R>(f: (item: T) => R): Observable<R>;
    scan<R>(f: (prev: R, next: T) => R): Observable<R>;
  }

  declare class Observable<T> implements CoreOperators<T> {
    observableSpecificMethod: (f: Function): Observable<T>
  }
}
```

Such that `Observable<T>` should get all the signatures in the interface and have its own.

Answer (score 0):

In flow you can represent interface as type and inheritance as intersection type:

```
type CoreOperators<T> = {
  map: <R>(f: (item: T) => R) => Observable<R>;
  scan: <R>(f: (prev: R, next: T) => R) => Observable<R>;
};

type Observable<T> = CoreOperators<T> & {
  observableSpecificMethod: (f: Function) => Observable<T>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out just a little bit ago that you can do `class A` and `class B mixins A` and that might be the closest thing I have to work with...

So maybe something like

```
declare module 'rxjs' {
  declare class CoreOperators<T> {
    static from(array: T[] | rxjs$ArrayLike<T>): Observable<T>;
    static merge<R>(...sources: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>;

    do(f: (item: T) => any): Observable<T>;
    map<R>(f: (item: T) => R): Observable<R>;
    scan<R>(f: (prev: R, next: T) => R): Observable<R>;
    skip(count: number): Observable<T>;
    startWith(init: any): Observable<T>;
    take(count: number): Observable<T>;
  }

  declare class Observable<T> mixins CoreOperators<T> {
    subscribe(
      next: (item: T) => any,
      error?: (error: any) => any,
      complete?: (item: T) => any
    ): Subscription;
  }
}
```

Still digging, but this might be the only thing available right now.

Comment: I don't see the keyword `mixins` documented anywhere. Are you sure about this?